# Type assertion errors when casting from interface to actual object

Tags: go, type-assertion

Encountering type assertion errors in the example below.

Errors:

> 49: cannot convert z (type IZoo) to type Zoo: need type assertion
>
> 49: cannot assign to Zoo(z).animals

```
type IAnimal interface {}

type IZoo interface {}

type Zoo struct {
    animals map[string]IAnimal
}

func NewZoo() *Zoo {
    var z IZoo = &Zoo{}

    Zoo(z).animals = map[string]IAnimal{} // cannot convert z (type IZoo) to type Zoo: need type assertion
    
    return z // cannot use z (type IZoo) as type *Zoo in return argument: need type assertion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all: you need a [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15).

```
y := z.(Zoo)
y.animals = map[string]IAnimal{}
```

Comment: couldn't you do it in one line, do we need separate declaration and assignment

Comment: @user2727195 `z.(Zoo).animals =` what do you think this expression should do? What it does - it creates a temporary object that is to be thrown away after this statement. Hence, a question: what does it mean to assign a value to an object's field that you would not be able to access? You basically can remove that line and the observed behaviour of a program would not change.

Comment: @zerkms is there an explanation on the docs about this temporary object

Comment: I'm not sure. It's a generic knowledge - structs in Go copy on assignment.

Comment: to clarify, _everything_ in Go is a copy on assignment.